# Search for the most occurring value in a string with SQL

Tags: sql, string, count, sql-order-by

So if you have a string like:

```
"lorum ipsum testing with some dummy text lorum woop what testing again."
```

and you have a database table like:

```
ID |   TESTING
---------------
1  |   dummy
2  |   lorum
3  |   trol
4  |   haha
```

How do I check what value is the most occurring in the **string** using sql only.

So in this case it would return: `2 | lorum`.

At first I thought the `LOCATE()` function would be useful. I tried for example:

```
SELECT *, LOCATE(testing, "<<string comes here>>") FROM <table>
```

Is this possible? If not what would be the best approach?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Sure @GordonLinoff , I just didn't choose a database for my project yet and was considering either one of them. Next time I won't include them if I'm not sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you could use [handy regex method `REGEXP_COUNT()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm#SQLRF20014), available since version 11g:

```
select *
from mytable
order by regexp_count(
    'lorum ipsum testing with some dummy text lorum woop what testing again.',
    '(^|\W)' || testing || '(\W|$)'
) desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3d1630161b5058e77b7a4416bcd6c913)**:

```
ID | TESTING
-: | :------
 2 | lorum
```

Note: `fetch first 1 rows only` requires Oracle 12c (in earlier versions, you need a subquery and `ROWNUM`).

---

In Postgres, you can use [`regexp_matches()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) to generate an array of matches for each search word, and then count the elements:

```
select id, testing, count(m)
from 
    mytable t,
    regexp_matches(
        'lorum ipsum testing with some dummy text lorum woop what testing again.', 
        '\y' || t.testing || '\y',
        'g'
    ) m
group by id, testing
order by count(m)::int desc
limit 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=57e26c5518e01fe7dfd53f5b044eae7c)**

Answer (score 1):

This is painful, but you can use a `like` and some string manipulations to count the number of matches within the string:

```
select t.testing,
       (length(v.str) - length(replace(v.str, t.testing, ''))) / length(t.testing) as num_times 
from (values ('lorum ipsum testing with some dummy text lorum woop what testing again.')
     ) v(str) join
     t
     on str like concat('%', t.testing, '%')
order by num_times desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  This is generic.  In Postgres, I would split the string into words and do equality comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

With Postgres this is quite easy:

```
select word, count(*)
from regexp_split_to_table('lorum ipsum testing with some dummy text lorum woop what testing again.', '\s') as x(word)
group by word
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach (implemented in Ms-SQL) utilizing `STRING_SPLIT(<string>,<separator>)` to turn test string into a table. That table can be joined with the dictionary, and all matches counted using GROUP BY with a Count.
I called dictionary table `DICTIONARY`

```
SELECT sub.testing, COUNT(sub.testing) FROM 
(   SELECT d.testing FROM DICTIONARY d
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT('lorum ipsum testing with some dummy text lorum woop what testing again.', ' ') ) s
    ON d.testing = s.value
)   sub
GROUP BY sub.testing
ORDER BY COUNT(sub.testing) DESC
```

Results:  all matched values from the DICTIONARY table will be listed with the counts, in descending order